# Peculiar If Sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conditional-constructions, if

I'm not sure what is suggested here, can you shed light on this if usage:

> The history of efforts to regulate cigarette- and their relative ineffectiveness- demonstrated the power of the industry to disrupt public health, just as it had disrupted science. ***If** the tobacco industry **did not** invent special interest lobbying, they raised it to a new art form in the Establishment of Tobacco Institute in 1958.* Each time Congress took up the question of tobacco and public health, proposed regulations were either fully dismantled or ....

Comment: Did you copy this? It has a number of errors.

Comment: Yes, it is from the book 'the cigarette century' written by Allan M. Brandt, page 5.  They are the exact words I've read on the book.

Comment: On the book? Also, this does not make sense "in the Establishment of Tobacco Institute in 1958"

Comment: @ErenYucel - Please check your transcription more carefully.  I have found a copy of the book and you made several errors that make the text more confusing.  For example, it should be "...in the **e**stablishment of **the** Tobacco Institute..."

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right ^^ Thank you for helping

Comment: Read _If.._ as _Even if..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some might think that the tobacco industry invented special interest lobbying, but it did not. However, it developed the techniques used very considerably by establishing the Tobacco Institute in 1958.

To make/turn something into an art form (or a new art form) is:

> to do something so often that you become very good at it

[Make/turn something into a an art form (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-turn-something-into-an-art-form#:%7E:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary,into%20an%20art%20form%E2%80%A2)

If my son did not invent the idea of breaking windows, he raised it to an art form after he obtained a powerful catapult.